# サイドバーを固定させるグリッドレイアウトを作ったが、iPadでスクロールがひっかかる。PCサイズでもややひっかかりを感じる。

Tags: css, html5

サイドバーを固定させるグリッドレイアウトを作ったが、iPadでスクロールがひっかります。

下記がコードになります。コンテンツに高さを持たさせるために AやBといったアルファベット一文字を多用していますが、そこはコンテンツに高さを持たせるためなので気にしないでください。

環境: Mac OS 10.15.5, Chrome Version 88.0.4324.192 (Official Build) (x86_64)

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/main-space.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="mainSpace">
        <div class="mainSpaceSide">
            <ul>
                <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>
                <li>D</li><li>E</li><li>F</li>
                <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>
                <li>D</li><li>E</li><li>F</li>
                <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>
                <li>D</li><li>E</li><li>F</li>
                <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>
                <li>D</li><li>E</li><li>F</li>
                <li>A</li><li>B</li><li>C</li>
                <li>D</li><li>E</li><li>F</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="mainSpaceBody">
            a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>a<br>
            b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>b<br>
            c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>c<br>
            d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>d<br>
            e<br>e<br>e<br>e<br>e<br>e<br>e<br>
            f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>f<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

CSS:

```
.mainSpace {
    min-height: 100vh;
    display: grid;
    grid-template: 
        "a-side a-body" 100vh
    /    320px 1fr;
}
.mainSpaceSide {
    grid-area: a-side;
    background-color: blue;
    overflow: scroll;
}
.mainSpaceBody {
    grid-area: a-body;
    background-color: green;
    overflow: scroll;
}
```

現象をしめした画像:

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

また、なんとも形容しがたいのですが、普通のPCサイズでも右側のスクロール範囲を一度全部下までスクロールさせたあと、一番上までスクロールで戻そうとすると、先頭（一番上）で、ひっかかりを感じます。（なので、iPadが顕著に現象がわかるだけで、おそらくなんらかのひっかかりをおこしてしまうよくないコードになっていると思うのですが、原因がわかりません）

また、雑多な情報になってしまいますが、PCでブラウザサイズの横幅を縮めてiPadほどの大きさにしたときはこんなにヒドくひっかかったりしません。なので`viewport`の設定があやしいのではないかとも推測していますが、はっきりしません。

追記:
iPhoneでも右側を下までスクロールしたあとで、上にスクロールするとひっかかって戻せない事に気づきました。下記にスクリーンショットを記載しますが、スクロールバーが２本出ているのがこの現象を引き起こしていそうな気がするのですが、気がするだけで、CSS的になにが原因でどう修復するかわかっていません。

[image: 画像の説明をここに入力]

Comment: `body` 要素の `margin` を 0 にした場合にも引っ掛かりを感じますか？

Comment: @supa さん　はい。ひっかかります。

Comment: @supa さん。0にした場合は、下まで勢いよくスクロールさせて、白い領域（Body部）が見えるようにバウンスさせると、ひっかかって操作できなくなりました。

Comment: ご確認いただきありがとうございます。1枚目の画像はChromeのデベロッパーツールだと思います。私も質問文のコードをデベロッパーツールで検証したのですが、「ここより下にスクロールできない」が再現出来ませんでした。コードは検証に用いたものと同じでしょうか？また質問者さんの使用しているブラウザ・OSのバージョン情報などを追記していただけると助かります。

Comment: @supa さん。試していただきありがとございます。環境を追記しました。再現できるコードを作るためにもともとのコードをいろいろいじっていたので、もしかしたら不備があるかもしれないですが、掲載したコードと検証したコードは同じはずです。また、実機のiPadでアクセスした場合もなんとも形容しがたい引っ掛かりがありました。

Comment: 追記ありがとうございます。私の使用OSはWindows 10ですが、少なくともWindows版の最新版Chromeでは問題の再現が出来なさそうです。もしかするとMac版のChromeに何かバグが存在するのかもしれません。お力になれずすみません。